# Unable to parse any XML input. Error on line 5: The reference to entity "utm_medium"

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-entities

I am getting an XML parsing error:

> Unable to parse any XML input. Error on line 5: The reference to entity `utm_medium` must end with the `;` delimiter. You most likely forgot to escape `&` into `&amp;`

with the following, the error is with the `xhtml:link` tag, URL, I tried changing `&` to `&amp;` but it won't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.com/financing/?utm_source=website&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=YBF&amp;utm_id=Yellow+Bar+Financing</loc>
      <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www..com/financing/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=YBF&utm_id=Yellow+Bar+Financing" />
      <lastmod>20015-04-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
<xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another `&utm_medium` on the next line that you missed, along with several other `&` characters that similarly must be changed to `&amp;`.

Here's your XML with all `&` properly replaced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.com/financing/?utm_source=website&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=YBF&amp;utm_id=Yellow+Bar+Financing</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www..com/financing/?utm_source=website&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=YBF&amp;utm_id=Yellow+Bar+Financing" />
    <lastmod>20015-04-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

The above XML is now well-formed.

Note that there is, at least in your posted XML, and extraneous `<xml>` open tag at the end of your document.